# Como desativar o teclado em C# Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, teclado

Boa Galera, estou enfrentando um problema com minha aplicação quando eu aperto a tecla ALT, eu não estou esperando nenhum tipo de interação por meio do teclado, mas mesmo assim exclusivamente essa tecla dá esse erro  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então não sei o porquê esse erro, acho que é devido uma biblioteca que uso para fazer reconhecimento facial, ou porque o Form que dá erro está sendo chamada por outro form de uma forma incorreta, não sei , em fim  queria desativar o teclado , pois a aplicação nessa parte não necessita do teclado.

Comment: Resumo, apertando a tecla Alt durante a execução do projeto acontece esse erro?

Comment: Sim,  é muito estranho isso

Comment: Já tentou colocar essa linha de código dentro de um bloco `try { } catch { }`?

Comment: Sim, mesmo com try catch dá erro

Comment: O erro pode ser na configuração de Layouts de teclado do Windows, e ocorre com teclas especiais (alt, lgr, Windows Key, etc.) Tente adicionar e remover um Keyboard layout no painel de controle.

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso uma função do Windows, ela trava a iteração com o teclado e mouse também.

```
 public class Utilidades 
 {

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   public static extern bool BlockInput(bool Blk);

 }
```

Uso ela assim:

```
Utilidades.BlockInput(true); //bloqueia
// codigos
Utilidades.BlockInput(false) // desbloqueia
```

adicionar using do seguinte namespace

> System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Comment: Não funcionou, esse APP vem dá onde ?

Comment: é nome da sua classe. vou editar o código

Comment: Mesmo assim, não foi, digo eu importei aí não deu erro de importação ou sintaxe , digo que não teve efeito nenhum, por exemplo eu tenho um campo lá e continuo digitando

Comment: acabei de criar um projeto windows forms, com um textbox e um botão. também criei a classe acima. então no botão chamei Utilidades.BlockInput(true). Travou o teclado e  mouse. Só libera com Ctrl + Alt + Del ou chamando o método com false

Comment: Se chamar o método com true, e com false, logo em seguida, não vai dar o efeito. precisa ter outras execuções que levem um tempo que você possa perceber.

Comment: não sei viu,  tipo o problema é que eu estou tornando um painel visible = true em um método que é chamado por uma outra thread,  embora eu utilize o invoke .... ele mostra lá o painel tudo certinho , eu posso aperta qualquer tecla menos o ALT ou TAB que gera exceção acima